# How to keep Google from indexing the Session ID in the URL?

Tags: url, session, web-crawler, sessionid

One of my sites is for old mobile phones that don't accept cookies so it uses a URL-based Session ID.

However, Google is indexing the Session ID, so when my site is searched on Google, all the results come up with a specific Session ID.

On most occasions, that Session ID is no longer valid by the time a guest clicks on it, but I've had at least one case where a guest clicked on a link from Google and it actually logged them into someone else's account, which is obviously a huge security flaw.

So how can I keep Google from indexing the Session ID in my URL's?  In case it helps, the  Session ID has always been set to "**Representative URL**" in Google's Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by placing a robots.txt file in your root web directory to tell Googlebot and all other crawlers not to crawl URLs with that attribute.

Here is an example:

Lets say the URL you want to block is in the form of:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html?id=1234
```

The robots.txt syntax to block URLs with the id attribute is:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*id
```

You can find out more about robots.txt at http://www.robotstxt.org

Read more about this at http://www.seochat.com/c/a/Search-Engine-Optimization-Help/Preventing-Duplicate-Content-on-an-ECommerce-Site-from-Session-IDs/1/

Comment: The problem with this solution is that ALL my URL's (as far as Google is concerned) have the Session ID in the URL, so this would block ALL pages from the Googlebot crawler.  The solution I need is for Google to index the URL without the Session ID.  Is that even possible?

Comment: You'll still need the same robots.txt file to keep crawlers fro following inbound links to URLs that have the session ID attribute.  I suggest adding a sitemap to your site AND making sure that the URL that is registered with Google's webwaster tools is one without the session ID attribute.  The 2nd link in my posted answer shows how to specify a sitemap in robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls, you can set canonical urls and google-bot will use this url to crawl your webpage, this can also solve duplicate url issues for the same webpage.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers