# How to cleanup URLs indexed by google

Tags: seo

so I made a mistake in my application which caused thousands of URLs to be indexed by google with the session id appended. What should I do to remove all those session id's from the google index? I'd like to only have the page indexed minus the session id.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @John Conde It was clearly tagged as SEO, so I'm a little confused as to why it's off topic?

Comment: Click on the SEO tag and read it :)

Comment: Well then stackoverflow is providing poor UX if it's offered as a choice on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with an edit to your [robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500531/how-to-keep-google-from-indexing-the-session-id-in-the-url). Also, there's a webmasters stackexchange -- consider checking there for your answer in the future, I know they have an SEO tag.

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt stops crawling, it doesnt stop urls being indexed.

You could use a [canonical tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to consolidate the urls to their parent url and/or [parameter handling](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/new-parameter-handling-tool-helps-with.html) in webmaster tools.